# How to connect two modules by systemC tlm_fifo<float>?

Tags: c++, systemc

I am still a novice for writing systemC-TLM. Now, I want to connect two modules by tlm_fifoFF. I am searching examples for a long time on net. But no use. Please help to give some ideas or examples how to achieve this.

This is my architecture:

[image]

and,this is my error information:

[image]

---

this is "main.cpp"

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "merlin2.h"

#include "tlm.h"
#include <tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_fifo/tlm_fifo.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_1_interfaces/tlm_fifo_ifs.h>
using namespace sc_core;
using namespace tlm;
using namespace tlm_utils;
using namespace std;

int sc_main(int argc, char** argv){

    Merlin2 merlin_test("merlin2_JW");

    sc_start();
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

this is "merlin2.cpp"

```
#include "merlin2.h"
Merlin2::Merlin2(const sc_module_name& name)
{
    ProcessEngine PE_TEST("test_PE");
    test_PE TP("PE_test");
    tlm::tlm_fifo <float> FF ("fifo");

    TP.out(FF);
    PE_TEST.in(FF);
}
```

this is "merlin2.h"

```
#ifndef __MERLIN2_H__
#define __MERLIN2_H__
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <systemc.h>

#include "pe.h"
#include "test_PE.h"

class Merlin2: public sc_module 
{
    public:

        SC_HAS_PROCESS(Merlin2);
        Merlin2(const sc_module_name& name);

};

#endif
```

---

this is "pe.cpp"

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "pe.h"

using namespace std;
ProcessEngine::ProcessEngine(const sc_module_name& name):in("in")
{ 
    cout << "before SC_THREAD(run)" << endl;
    SC_THREAD(run);
    cout << "after SC_THREAD(run)" << endl;
}

void ProcessEngine::run()
{   
    int N = in.nb_get();
    cout <<  " N=" << N << endl;

    wait(1,SC_NS);
}
```

---

this is "pe.h"

```
#ifndef __PE_H__
#define __PE_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include "tlm.h"
#include <tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_fifo/tlm_fifo.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_1_interfaces/tlm_fifo_ifs.h>
using namespace sc_core;
using namespace tlm;
using namespace tlm_utils;
using namespace std;


class ProcessEngine: public sc_module
{
    public:

        tlm::tlm_fifo<float>  in;
        void run();

        ProcessEngine(const sc_module_name& name);
        SC_HAS_PROCESS(ProcessEngine);


};

#endif
```

---

this is "test_PE.cpp"

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "test_PE.h"
using namespace std;

test_PE::test_PE(const sc_module_name& name):out("out")
{ 
    cout << "before start_test " << endl;
    SC_THREAD(start_test);
    cout << "After start_test " << endl;
}

void test_PE::start_test()
{
    float A=5;
    in.nb_put(A);
    cout << "A=" << A << endl;
    wait(1,SC_NS);
}
```

---

this is "test_PE.h"

```
#ifndef __TESTPE_H__
#define __TESTPE_H__
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <systemc.h>

#include "tlm.h"
#include <tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_initiator_socket.h>
#include <tlm_utils/multi_passthrough_target_socket.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_channels/tlm_fifo/tlm_fifo.h>
#include <tlm_core/tlm_1/tlm_req_rsp/tlm_1_interfaces/tlm_fifo_ifs.h>

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace tlm;
using namespace tlm_utils;
using namespace std;

class test_PE:public sc_module
{
    public:
        tlm::tlm_fifo<float>  out;  
        test_PE(const sc_module_name& name);
        SC_HAS_PROCESS(test_PE);
        void start_test();
    private:
        float A;
};
#endif
```

---

Comment: improved your formatting, and embedded images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing SystemC/TLM notions and especially ports and channels.

- `tlm_fifo` is a channel. It can be used to connect two ports. It's the yellow part of your image.

However, you can't directly connect a channel to a module. Instead, you need to use ports in each module you want to connect the channel. A port is associated to an interface defining methods you can use. In your case, you use `nb_get(...)` and `nb_put(...)`.

For `tlm_fifo`, you can use these ports:

- `sc_port< tlm_nonblocking_put_if<float> >`
- `sc_port< tlm_nonblocking_get_if<float> >`

[image: TLM-1.0 example]

Finally, you create instances of your modules in your `Merlin2` constructor. Objects are not persisted and deleted at the end of the constructor. They should be member of the class. Here is a complete working example of TLM-1.0 using `tlm_fifo` with non blocking interface.

Note: You're mixing TLM-2.0 and TLM-1.0 headers. I removed useless headers.

---

main.cpp

```
#include <systemc>
#include "merlin2.h"

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace std;

int sc_main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Merlin2 merlin_test("merlin2_JW");
    sc_start();
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

merlin2.h

```
#ifndef __MERLIN2_H__
#define __MERLIN2_H__
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <systemc>

#include "pe.h"
#include "test_PE.h"

class Merlin2: public sc_module
{
public:
    Merlin2(const sc_module_name& name);
    tlm::tlm_fifo <float> FF;
    ProcessEngine PE_TEST;
    test_PE TP;
};
#endif
```

merlin2.cpp

```
#include "merlin2.h"

Merlin2::Merlin2(const sc_module_name& name):
        PE_TEST("test_PE"),
        TP("PE_test"),
        FF("fifo")
{
    TP.out(FF);
    PE_TEST.in(FF);
}
```

pe.h

```
#ifndef __PE_H__
#define __PE_H__

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <systemc>
#include <tlm>

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace tlm;
using namespace std;

class ProcessEngine: public sc_module
{
public:
    sc_port< tlm_nonblocking_get_if<float> >  in;
    void run();
    ProcessEngine(const sc_module_name& name);
    SC_HAS_PROCESS(ProcessEngine);
};

#endif
```

pe.cpp

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include "pe.h"

using namespace std;

ProcessEngine::ProcessEngine(const sc_module_name& name):
        in("in")
{
    SC_THREAD(run);
}

void ProcessEngine::run()
{
    sc_core::wait(1, SC_NS);
    float N = 0;
    bool r = in->nb_get(N);
    cout <<  " N=" << N << endl;
}
```

test_PE.cpp

```
#include <systemc>
#include "test_PE.h"

using namespace std;

test_PE::test_PE(const sc_module_name& name):
        out("out")
{
    SC_THREAD(start_test);
}

void test_PE::start_test()
{
    float A=5;
    out->nb_put(A);
    cout << "A=" << A << endl;
    sc_core::wait(1, SC_NS);
}
```

test_PE.h

```
#ifndef __TESTPE_H__
#define __TESTPE_H__

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <systemc>
#include <tlm>

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace tlm;
using namespace std;

class test_PE:public sc_module
{
public:
    sc_port< tlm_nonblocking_put_if<float> >  out;
    test_PE(const sc_module_name& name);
    SC_HAS_PROCESS(test_PE);
    void start_test();
private:
    float A;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Guillaume ,thanks a lot!!!!!!!! I love u so much! It can work on my server :) ,and I got what was wrong. 

By the way , Is there an approcach that using TLM2.0(initiator socket 、target socket) to stimulate FIFO behavior like my merlin2 picture ?

JW

Comment: TLM-2.0 is conceptually different. TLM-1.0 communications are based on FIFOs while in TLM-2.0 communications are based on sockets and transport calls. You can simulate a FIFO with TLM-2.0 adding a FIFO module between test_PE and PE. You would have something like test_PE (initiator socket) <---> (target socket) FIFO (initiator socket) <----> (target socket) PE

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation!.I got it! Have a nice day~